# Error message shows up when adding a class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class

I have a class called PrimeNumber that I wrote recently, which worked absolutely fine with a Foundation Tool and a Mac application. However, trying to use it with an iPhone application fails. I added the .m and the .h files to my project and imported the .h file to my ViewController.h like this:

```
#import "PrimeNumber.h"
```

After trying to use a method declared in my PrimeNumber class and run my application, Xcode showed me two errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PrimeNumber", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The PrimeNumber.h and PrimeNumber.m files are not red in the Project navigator. Product > Clean doesn't work either. Also, because my classes aren't declared in a framework, I do not think something like that can be the problem.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Edit: changing the class name to PrimeNumbers, then creating a new Objective-C class called PrimeNumber and copy-and-pasting the complete contents of .h and .m files of the PrimeNumbers class into the .h and .m files of the PrimeNumber class worked for me. Weird, but it worked. :)

Comment: Does `PrimeNumber.h` also import `ViewController.h`?

Comment: The renaming and copy&pasting worked because when you add a new class through Xcode it adds it to the Compile Sources build phase automatically. It doesn't do that when you drag and drop source files into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it to the "Compile Sources" Build Phase as well.
Project -> Targets -> [Your Target] -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources (just drag `PrimeNumber.m` in there)